# how to set hinge joint in sliding door

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this sliding door where i want to use hing joint[image]

but i am confused about two properties of hinge join which are  Anchor  & Axis.
My sliding door current transform is:

[image]

Do i need to mention

Comment: which version of unity are you using?

Comment: unity 5.4 using